# Pandas Excel Writer

Tags: python, pandas

Estou com um problema ao tentar escrever um arquivo em excel com o pandas. Quando tento escrever ele apresenta a seguinte mensagem.

> ZIP does not support timestamps before 1980

Achando que poderia ser algum problema com os dados criei um arquivo de teste e mesmo assim ocorre o erro.

Segue o código abaixo.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],columns=['A','B','C'])

writer=pd.ExcelWriter('teste.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'teste',index=False)
writer.save()
```

Segue também a mensagem de erro completa:

```
  writer.save()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py",              line 1952, in save
  return self.book.close()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 306, in close
  self._store_workbook()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 679, in _store_workbook
  xlsx_file.write(os_filename, xml_filename)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 1710, in write
  zinfo = ZipInfo.from_file(filename, arcname)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 518, in from_file
  zinfo = cls(arcname, date_time)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 357, in __init__
  raise ValueError('ZIP does not support timestamps before 1980')
  ValueError: ZIP does not support timestamps before 1980
```

Comment: a versão que eu estava era a 1.1.8 que estava com esse problema, consegui resolve-lo atualizando para a 1.1.9, lançada ontem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isto é um [bug](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/535) do xlsxwriter, tente fazer um upgrade no pacote para pelo menos a versão 1.1.4. Comandos para Anaconda:

```
conda update xlsxwriter
```

ou com pip:

```
pip install --upgrade xlsxwriter
```

Comment: nossa - valeu - eu já ia perguntar nos comentários se o relógio do computador do A.P. estava correto! :-)